# NameError: global name 'Entry' is not defined. Python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

tengo el siguiente error y no se como sacar la variable de una funcion a otra.

> NameError: global name 'EntryE' is not defined

Mi objetivo es que tras haber escrito un nombre en el entry y haber pulsado un button, se borre un registro específco de una base de datos sqlite.

He intentado poner un `global EntryE` pero me sigue saltando el mismo error.

No quiero sacar el Entry de la funcion porque quiero que el entry aparezca tras pulsar un Button, lo que llama a la funcion `EliminarProd` para que aparezca el entry y poder escribir ahi.

(He omitido la parte del codigo en donde pongo `.pack()` a los widgets.)

```
N7=StringVar()

def EliminarProd
   entryE=Entry(frame,justify='right',state='normal',textvariable=N7)``



def EliminarDef():
    Cursor=Conexion.cursor()
    Cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Nombre="+EntryE.get())


filemenu.add_command(label='Eliminar Producto',command=EliminarProd)

BEliminar=Button(frame,text='Buscar y Eliminar producto',command=EliminarDef)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y si a la función le pasas la variable?

```
def EliminarDef(entry):
    Cursor=Conexion.cursor()
    Cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Nombre="+entry.get())
```

De todas maneras, como estás usando una StringVar() en el entry (`textvariable=N7`) te recomiendo que en el delete uses `"DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Nombre="+N7.get()` ya que precisamente las StringVar existen para darnos un acceso rápido al valor de los entry sin tener que tocar el entry:

```
def EliminarDef():
    Cursor=Conexion.cursor()
    Cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Nombre="+N7.get())
```

Y si tu StringVar no es accesible desde dentro del método, siempre puedes hacerla accesible o pasarla al método igual que con el entry.